# ExcelLibrary Creating Too Many Worksheets

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I am trying to write output to an Excel workbook using ExcelLibrary.  I want this workbook to contain only one sheet but I can't find any way to either create a workbook with only one sheet or remove the extra sheets after creation.  All of the examples I have found do not work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Worksheets are available to you via the `Worksheets` property, which is simply a generic list of Worksheet objects - i.e. `List<Worksheet>`.

You can treat this list like any generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and use `Clear()`, `Remove()`, etc. to manipulate the list of worksheets.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.Worksheets.Clear(); // remove all worksheets

Worksheet mySheet = new Worksheet();
workbook.Worksheets.Add(mySheet); // add a new worksheet
workbook.Worksheets.Remove(mySheet); // remove a particular worksheet
workbook.Worksheets.RemoveAt(4); // remove a worksheet at specific index
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `workbook.Worksheets.Clear();` but I still end up with extra worksheets.  Also, when I try to delete them by index I always throw an index out of bounds exception -- which is weird since it should be one or the other.

Comment: My apologies.  I was adding the worksheet in the wrong spot.  Your example is perfectly correct.  Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin You're welcome. Glad to help. May I suggest you mark my answer as correct? Thanks.